# Null/Empty binding when getting DataTemplate from ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I'm trying to get a DatatTemplate from a ResourceDictionary in code. The problem is when I'm trying to save it to string I get all the Binding location to be either empty or null.

Here is my piece of code

```
    ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
        dictionary.Source = new Uri("WpfApplication1;component/Dict.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        DataTemplate template = (DataTemplate) dictionary["helloTextBox"];
        string save = XamlWriter.Save(template.LoadContent());
```

I'd be happy for any insight.

Thanks

Comment: Where is this code executed? in the ctor? are you sure you do this after the dataTemplate is applied?

Comment: I do this in the ctor of a sample app (whay should be different in somewhere else?) - What do you mean by DataTemplate applied?

Comment: Override the `OnApplyTemplate` method and try executing the code from there

Comment: Override it where? My application is simple - mvvm and a resource dictionary

Comment: Please post the entire code. How is your Dict.xaml defined, How do you define your bindings and so on ...
Its hard to say what your problem is with the code snippet you posted ...

Comment: Found the solution - had to register to BindingExpression TypeDescriptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to register a binding converter for BindingExpression in TypeConverter in order for the serialize to work on bindings as by default they are not serialized.

Needs to add this class as the ExpressionConverter

```
public class BindingConverter : ExpressionConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
    if (destinationType == typeof(MarkupExtension))
    {
        BindingExpression bindingExpression = value as BindingExpression;
        if (bindingExpression == null)
        {
            throw new FormatException("Expected binding, but didn't get one");
        }
        return bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
    }
    return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
}
```

}

and then use this method to register where I do the XamlWriter.Save part

```
private void Register()
{
    Attribute[] attr = new Attribute[1];
    TypeConverterAttribute vConv = new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(BindingConverter));
    attr[0] = vConv;
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(BindingExpression), attr);
}
```

Taken from here:
[Setting template binding in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239871/setting-template-binding-in-code-behind)